# Were there any black actors in 'V for Vendetta'?

Tags: casting, v-for-vendetta

I can't recall seeing any black people in the movie, not even among the crowds.

Were there any black actors in *V for Vendetta*? If not, then why not?

Comment: I know this is late but.....does it really matter if there were or weren't? Is it going to affect your enjoyment of the movie?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There were a number of black actors in the various flashbacks

**The Doctor's Journal:**
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Valerie's Story**
[image]

**The Unmasking**
[image]
[image]
[image]

As to why there were no black actors in the main cast, the implication (stated rather more clearly in the source comic) was that they were among the "undesirables" who were rounded up during the 'Norsefire purges' and either exterminated or experimented upon to death.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Actually there was a black man in bed with his male lover in the montage of Norsefire cleansings we see as Valerie tells her story. The reason for there are no black people from the POV of the movie present is because England had been ethnically cleansed as [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norsefire) page explains: 'people who were not white, Christian, and heterosexual were rounded up and sent to concentration camps'.

Comment: "*The reason for there are no black people from the POV of the movie present is because England had been ethnically cleansed.*" - Do you have any sources for this?

Comment: @Catija [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norsefire) Wikipedia article tells that 'people who were not white, Christian, and heterosexual were rounded up and sent to concentration camps'.

Comment: Then you should include that in your answer and quote it directly. We try to avoid questions that direct people to other sites to fully understand what's being discussed. See [this SE Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) topic on the subject.

Answer (score -4):

V was black. When they showed Valorie in line at camp, they went too far with the camera and showed us the Man in Room Five. He was black.

Comment: If I remember the scene correctly, I think that was more lighting / dramatic effect. Can you load a screenshot? I don't have a copy handy to do so myself.

Comment: Can you provide a timestamp?